# How to connect the android phone on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: android, ubuntu

I tried to test my application on my android phone, but the it can't be able to detect the device compatibility. The debug mode on phone is enabled.

My phone: Motorola.
My ubuntu: 10.04.
IDE: Eclipse.

I even tried to add the following line:
SUBSYSTEMS==”usb”, ATTRS{idVendor}==”22b8″, ATTRS{idProduct} ==”41db”, MODE=”0600"
to my /etc/udev/rules.d/90-android.rules.

But every time I tried to run the application, the device can't be detectable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want mode to be 0666 to give read/write permissions.  My rule looks something like this:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666"

You may need to run sudo reload udev and/or disconnect and reconnect the phone.

Answer (score 2):

if `adb devices` says something like permission denied try
sudo -i
adb kill-server
adb devices

Comment: so adb devices says something like  
"HT041PL11136    device"?